# Jersey response logging filter excluding response body for GET

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, jersey

I am developing REST web server using Jersey and Tomcat and I have Jersey logging filters to log request and response. I have this in my web.xml and it worked.

I'd like to disable logging response body for GET responses while logging response body for PUT and POST. How do I do this?

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.logging.DisableEntitylogging</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could extend the filter like this :

```
public class MyFilter extends com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter {

// other (maybe fundamental) code omitted for brevity

  @Override
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
      if(!request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
          return super.filter(request);   
      }
      return request;
  }

}
```

and then change your web.xml to use it instead of

```
<param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
```